# how to call any method when user tocuhes any part of the screen in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, methods, touch

I have a ipad app in which i want if user touches any part of the screen then it should show alert. I have studied method like touch started and ended point but how to call method on touch if user touches screen.

Comment: Read this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

  //Do stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 3.2 and higher, you can use gesture recognizers. For example, this is how you would handle a tap event:

```
//The setup code (in viewDidLoad in your view controller)
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
[singleFingerTap release];

//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

  //Do stuff here...
}
```

There are a bunch of built in gestures as well. Check out the docs for iOS event handling and UIGestureRecognizer. bunch of sample code up on [github](https://github.com/neror/UIGestureExamples) that might help.